# Remove leftmost part of Path in UriBuilder

Tags: c#, .net

I need to remove leftmost part of the path in the `URL`. For example:

**`http://mywebsite.com/part1/part2/part3`**

Expected result:

**`http://mywebsite.com/part2/part3`**

I'd like to get this done in the most readable way for example by using **`UriBuilder`**.
I see that it has property `Path` but is there a way to manipulate the path without having to use some sort of trimming and cutting of the string itself?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Investigate `string.IndexOf` and `string.Substring` - much simpler than RegEx (sorry @Cid)

Comment: I want to maintain that part of the code readable so I was mostly looking into what can be offered by UriBuilder because when using trim/indexof/substring makes code hard to read and understand. Just wondering if there is a way it can be done in a clean and readable manner.

Comment: As the old adage says - having made the decision to solve the problem with regex, you now have 2 problems.

Comment: have a look at the `Segments` property of a Uri.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy enough to do with `UriBuilder` and a bit of string manipulation:

```
var builder = new UriBuilder("http://mywebsite.com/part1/part2/part3");
builder.Path = builder.Path.Substring(builder.Path.IndexOf('/',1));
Console.WriteLine(builder.Uri);
```

Live example: https://rextester.com/SXA2367

Comment: @Sparrow you might even want to wrap it up in an extension like the other answer (albeit with the right functionality)

Comment: that would make sense to have that kind of an extension in case I need to do it more than once. But in my case there is no need.

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, to mention the [URI.Segments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.segments?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Uri.Segments);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) property, which return all the path parts already conveniently split in a string array, which may come in handy if the new URI should be composed of different parts.
It could provide some more flexibility in some cases.

In this case, the `Segments` array is:

```
{string[4]}
    [0]: "/"
    [1]: "part1/"
    [2]: "part2/"
    [3]: "part3"
```

So, in this context, the `Path` could be built with:

```
var builder = new UriBuilder("http://mywebsite.com/part1/part2/part3");
builder.Path = string.Concat(builder.Uri.Segments.Skip(2));
```

The `builder.URI.AbsolutePath` will then be:

```
http://mywebsite.com/part2/part3
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible using just the `UriBuilder`

The cleanest way I would do it is to have an extension method off the `UriBuilder` below is an example I quickly whipped up

```
public static UriBuilder RemoveFirstPartOfPath(this UriBuilder b)
{
    var s = b.Path.Split('/');
    var shorter = s.Skip(1);
    b.Path = string.Join("/", shorter);
    return b;
}
```